# Executing And Interacting With Command Line Commands in C

Tags: java, c, automation

I am attempting to create an automatic deployment system, so I may be approaching this all wrong. Basically our installs consist of moving out the source code(not with git, but a home grown RCS wrapper), running make commands, nissing config files, and then running the custom up/down/update scripts to get the servers back into motion. The system is a Real Time system so everything has to be scheduled around our operators. In our environment we have access to C, KornShell, FORTRAN, Pascal and Java.

My current Idea is to write something that you can execute command line commands, interact with the stdin/out and track the exit codes of the process and its children. From there we could set up config files that say the command, its expected exit code, if it needs to have user input to wait for a go/no go time as well as a back out command. My question is where should I start looking to accomplish this task in C or Java. I have found a few resources, but I can't seem to track the child processes. Is there other ways of doing automatic deployments that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use standard [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for this propose.

An example:

```
public class GNUMakeExecutor {

    private static final String GNU_MAKE = "make";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File sourceRootDir = new File("/home/dev/project_root");
        String makeFileName = "MyCustomMakeFile";
        List<String> command = new ArrayList<>();
        command.add(GNU_MAKE);
        // and add/check some flag to skip, in case of pre-compiled headers
        if( Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() > 1 ) {
            command.add("-j"+Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        }
        if(null != makeFileName && makeFileName.length() > 0) {
            command.add("-f");
            command.add(makeFileName);
        }
        String path = System.getenv("PATH") + File.pathSeparator +  "/opt/my_additional_util/bin";
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().directory(sourceRootDir)
                .command(command).redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT).redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
        pb.environment().put("PATH", path);
        Process makeProcess = pb.start();
        int exitCode = makeProcess.waitFor();
        if(exitCode != 0)
            System.err.println("Build failed, exit code: " + exitCode );
        else
            System.out.println("Build success");
    }

}
```

And in the same time, you can use set of depending tasks using [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/).
I.e. make C project first using make/cmake etc, and then execute some bash/docker/cheef/maven/ etc. then.